# Swipe to switch page with JQUERY

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I was searching on stackoverflow to find code to swipe between my app and I found the below jquery code. From the answers I read that it works fine, but when I put it on my page, it fails to work.

Javascript:

```
$('div.ui-page').live("swipeleft", function () {
    var nextpage = $(this).next('div[data-role="page"]');
    if (nextpage.length > 0) {
        $.mobile.changePage(nextpage, "slide", false, true);
    }
});
$('div.ui-page').live("swiperight", function () {
    var prevpage = $(this).prev('div[data-role="page"]');
    if (prevpage.length > 0) {
        $.mobile.changePage(prevpage, {
            transition: "slide",
            reverse: true
        }, true, true);
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="news">
  <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" data-theme="b">
    <h1>Current Affairs</h1>
    <a href='source.html' class='ui-btn-left' data-icon="home">Home</a>
    <a href='#' class='ui-btn-right' data-icon='arrow-l' onclick="history.back(); return false">Back</a>
  </div>
  <div id="news_feed" data-role="content" data-theme="e">Loading Headlines, Please Wait</div>
  <div id="tv_links" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" data-role="footer" data-theme="b">
    <div data-role="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#business" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="info">Business News </a>

          <li><a href="#sportsnews" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="info">Sports News </a>

            <li>
              <a href="#weather_update" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="info">Weather </a>

              <li>
                <a href="#interactive" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="info">Get Live </a>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<p>
  <div data-role="page" id="business">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
      <h1>Business News</h1>
      <a href='source.html' class='ui-btn-left' data-icon="home">Home</a>
      <a href='#' class='ui-btn-right' data-icon='arrow-l' onclick="history.back(); return false">Back</a>
    </div>
    <div id="biz" data-role="content" data-theme="e">Loading Headlines, Please Wait</div>
    <div id="tv_links" data-position="fixed" data-role="footer" data-theme="b">
      <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>

          <li><a href="#business" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="info">Business News </a>

            <li><a href="#sportsnews" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="info">Sports News </a>
              <li>

                <a href="#weather_update" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="info">Weather </a>
                <li>

                  <a href="#interactive" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="info">Get Live </a>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</p>
<p>

  <div data-role="page" id="politics">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
      <h1>Politics</h1>
      <a href='source.html' class='ui-btn-left' data-icon="home">Home</a>
      <a href='#' class='ui-btn-right' data-icon='arrow-l' onclick="history.back(); return false">Back</a>
    </div>
    <div id="polit" data-role="content" data-theme="e">Loading Headlines, Please Wait</div>
    <div id="tv_links" data-position="fixed" data-role="footer" data-theme="b">
      <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>

          <li><a href="#business" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="info">Business News </a>

            <li><a href="#sportsnews" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="info">Sports News </a>
              <li>

                <a href="#weather_update" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="info">Weather </a>
                <li>

                  <a href="#interactive" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="info">Get Live </a>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</p>
<p>
  <div data-role="page" id="sportsnews">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
      <h1>Sports News</h1>
      <a href='source.html' class='ui-btn-left' data-icon="home">Home</a>
      <a href='#' class='ui-btn-right' data-icon='arrow-l' onclick="history.back(); return false">Back</a>
    </div>
    <div id="sports" data-role="content" data-theme="e">Loading Headlines, Please Wait</div>
    <div id="tv_links" data-position="fixed" data-role="footer" data-theme="b">
      <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>

          <li><a href="#business" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="info">Business News </a>

            <li><a href="#sportsnews" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="info">Sports News </a>
              <li>

                <a href="#weather_update" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="info">Weather </a>
                <li>

                  <a href="#interactive" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="info">Get Live </a>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</p>
<p>

  <div data-role="page" id="business_news">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
      <h1>Business News</h1>
      <a href='source.html' class='ui-btn-left' data-icon="home">Home</a>
      <a href='#' class='ui-btn-right' data-icon='arrow-l' onclick="history.back(); return false">Back</a>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="e">Loading Headlines, Please Wait</div>

    <div id="tv_links" data-position="fixed" data-role="footer" data-theme="b">
      <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>

          <li><a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="info">Business News </a>

            <li><a href="#sportsnews" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="info">Sports News </a>
              <li>

                <a href="#weather_update" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="info">Weather </a>
                <li>

                  <a href="#interactive" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="info">Get Live </a>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</p>
<p>
  <div id="interactive" data-role="page" data-theme="d" data-position="fixed">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
      <h1>Get Interactive</h1>
      <a href='source.html' class='ui-btn-left' data-icon="home">Home</a>
      <a href='#' class='ui-btn-right' data-icon='arrow-l' onclick="history.back(); return false">Back</a>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="e">
      <div data-role="collapsible-set">
        <div id="morning_show" data-role="collapsible" data-theme="d">

          <h3>Morning Show</h3>

          <script language="javascript">
            $.post('quest_rev.asp', $('#form1').serialize(), function () {
              // Do something
            });
          </script>
          <h3>&nbsp;</h3>
        </div>
        <div data-collapsed="true" data-role="collapsible" data-theme="d">
          <h3>E- News</h3>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>

        </div>
        <div data-collapsed="true" data-role="collapsible" data-theme="d">
          <h3>Political Programme</h3>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="tv_links" data-position="fixed" data-role="footer" data-theme="b">
      <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>

          <li><a href="#business" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="info">Business News </a>

            <li><a href="#sportsnews" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="info">Sports News </a>
              <li>

                <a href="#weather_update" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="info">Weather </a>
                <li>

                  <a href="#interactive" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="info">Get Live </a>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</p>
<div data-role="page" id="weather_update">
  <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
    <h1>Weather Update</h1>
    <a href='source.html' class='ui-btn-left' data-icon="home">Home</a>
    <a href='#' class='ui-btn-right' data-icon='arrow-l' onclick="history.back(); return false">Back</a>
  </div>
  <div id="weather" data-role="content" data-theme="e">Getting Updates, Please Wait</div>

  <div id="tv_links" data-position="fixed" data-role="footer" data-theme="b">
    <div data-role="navbar">
      <ul>

        <li><a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="info">Business News </a>

          <li><a href="#sportsnews" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="info">Sports News </a>
            <li>

              <a href="#weather_update" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="info">Weather </a>
              <li>

                <a href="#interactive" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="info">Get Live </a>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

Comment: Better you should download these libraries into your project and use. otherwise each time you load the page requests send to get these libraries and downloads the scripts, is this necessary for you.?

Comment: And i haven't find a div with class `ui-page`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some mistakes in your code above, that's why its not working.

1. You forgot to close `li` tags in your navbar links.
2. You have added `<p>` tags between pages.

Use the below code to navigate using swipe events.

```
$(document).on('swipeleft swiperight', function (event) {
    // next page
    if (event.type == 'swipeleft') {
        var nextPage = $.mobile.activePage.next('[data-role=page]');
        if (nextPage) {
            $.mobile.changePage(nextPage, {
                transition: "flip" // or any transition
            });
        }
    }
    // previous page
    if (event.type == 'swiperight') {
        var prevPage = $.mobile.activePage.prev('[data-role=page]');
        if (prevPage) {
            $.mobile.changePage(prevPage, {
                transition: "flip",
                reverse: true // reverse effect
            });
        }
    }
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/a9grq/)**

Comment: One thing i wanted to change the transition from flip to push, but when i change it to push it still flips. why?

Comment: @blay are you sure you replaced both `transition` to `slide`?

Comment: can you please check out this question for me on my page? this is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19675149/push-menu-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the close tags for your `<li>`s, for example, this:

```
<li>
  <a href="#business" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="info">Business News </a>
```

should be this:

```
<li>
  <a href="#business" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="info">Business News </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the code use jquery mobile, You have to add these scripts on the page.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try including the libraries:

```
<link href="jquery.mobile-1.3.2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js"></script>
```

I hope this helps you.

I've removed the html warnings.

Html:

```
<div data-role="page" id="news" class="demo-page" data-prev="weather_update" data-next="business">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" data-theme="b">
            <h1>Current Affairs</h1>
            <a href='source.html' class='ui-btn-left' data-icon="home">Home</a>
            <a href='#' class='ui-btn-right' data-icon='arrow-l' onclick="history.back(); return false">Back</a>
        </div>
        <div id="news_feed" data-role="content" data-theme="e">Loading Headlines, Please Wait</div>
        <div id="tv_links" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" data-role="footer" data-theme="b">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#business" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="info">Business News </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#sportsnews" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="info">Sports News </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#weather_update" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="info">Weather </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#interactive" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="info">Get Live </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="page" id="business" data-prev="news" data-next="politics">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
            <h1>Business News</h1>
            <a href='source.html' class='ui-btn-left' data-icon="home">Home</a>
            <a href='#' class='ui-btn-right' data-icon='arrow-l' onclick="history.back(); return false">Back</a>
        </div>
        <div id="biz" data-role="content" data-theme="e">Loading Headlines, Please Wait</div>
        <div id="Div1" data-position="fixed" data-role="footer" data-theme="b">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#business" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="info">Business News </a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#sportsnews" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="info">Sports News </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#weather_update" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="info">Weather </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#interactive" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="info">Get Live </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="page" id="politics" data-prev="business" data-next="sportsnews">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
            <h1>Politics</h1>
            <a href='source.html' class='ui-btn-left' data-icon="home">Home</a>
            <a href='#' class='ui-btn-right' data-icon='arrow-l' onclick="history.back(); return false">Back</a>
        </div>
        <div id="polit" data-role="content" data-theme="e">Loading Headlines, Please Wait</div>
        <div id="Div2" data-position="fixed" data-role="footer" data-theme="b">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#business" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="info">Business News </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#sportsnews" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="info">Sports News </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#weather_update" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="info">Weather </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#interactive" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="info">Get Live </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="page" id="sportsnews" data-prev="politics" data-next="business_news">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
            <h1>Sports News</h1>
            <a href='source.html' class='ui-btn-left' data-icon="home">Home</a>
            <a href='#' class='ui-btn-right' data-icon='arrow-l' onclick="history.back(); return false">Back</a>
        </div>
        <div id="sports" data-role="content" data-theme="e">Loading Headlines, Please Wait</div>
        <div id="Div3" data-position="fixed" data-role="footer" data-theme="b">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#business" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="info">Business News </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#sportsnews" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="info">Sports News </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#weather_update" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="info">Weather </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#interactive" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="info">Get Live </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="page" id="business_news" data-prev="sportsnews" data-next="weather_update">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
            <h1>Business News</h1>
            <a href='source.html' class='ui-btn-left' data-icon="home">Home</a>
            <a href='#' class='ui-btn-right' data-icon='arrow-l' onclick="history.back(); return false">Back</a>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" data-theme="e">Loading Headlines, Please Wait</div>
        <div id="Div4" data-position="fixed" data-role="footer" data-theme="b">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="info">Business News </a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#sportsnews" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="info">Sports News </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#weather_update" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="info">Weather </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#interactive" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="info">Get Live </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="interactive" data-role="page" data-theme="d" data-position="fixed">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
            <h1>Get Interactive</h1>
            <a href='source.html' class='ui-btn-left' data-icon="home">Home</a>
            <a href='#' class='ui-btn-right' data-icon='arrow-l' onclick="history.back(); return false">Back</a>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" data-theme="e">
            <div data-role="collapsible-set">
                <div id="morning_show" data-role="collapsible" data-theme="d">

                    <h3>Morning Show</h3>

                    <h3>&nbsp;</h3>
                </div>
                <div data-collapsed="true" data-role="collapsible" data-theme="d">
                    <h3>E- News</h3>
                    <p>&nbsp;</p>

                </div>
                <div data-collapsed="true" data-role="collapsible" data-theme="d">
                    <h3>Political Programme</h3>
                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="Div5" data-position="fixed" data-role="footer" data-theme="b">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#business" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="info">Business News </a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#sportsnews" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="info">Sports News </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#weather_update" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="info">Weather </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#interactive" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="info">Get Live </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="page" id="weather_update" data-prev="weather_update" data-next="news">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
            <h1>Weather Update</h1>
            <a href='source.html' class='ui-btn-left' data-icon="home">Home</a>
            <a href='#' class='ui-btn-right' data-icon='arrow-l' onclick="history.back(); return false">Back</a>
        </div>
        <div id="weather" data-role="content" data-theme="e">Getting Updates, Please Wait</div>
        <div id="Div6" data-position="fixed" data-role="footer" data-theme="b">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="info">Business News </a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#sportsnews" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="info">Sports News </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#weather_update" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="info">Weather </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#interactive" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="info">Get Live </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

change your script:

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "[data-role='page']", function () {
        var page = "#" + $(this).attr("id");

    $(document).on("swipeleft", page, function () {
        next = $(this).jqmData("next");
        console.log(next);
        if (next) {
            $.mobile.changePage("#" + next, { transition: "slide" });
        }
    });

    $(document).on("swiperight", page, function () {
        prev = $(this).jqmData("prev");
        if (prev) {
            $.mobile.changePage("#" + prev, { transition: "slide", reverse: true });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: please nothing works at the Demo. and please why should i place the jquery? is it in the body or the head of the page?

Comment: If you have included jQuery it is enough. Include the required jQuery mobile libraries. Including libraries in the head tag is the better way. For more details read [API Documentation](http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-mobile/getting-started/).

Comment: i've also included that on the page. you mean this?<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>